# Baby Rudin without knowing multivariate?

Tags: calculus, analysis, vector-analysis

I have read Spivak's *Calculus* and it has went well. I didn't have any problem with the rigorosity of the book at all.

Now, I have never had any experience in multivariate. I only have experience with basic high school calculus, linear algebra and the calculus from Spivak. Can I learn multivariate calculus directly from the *Baby Rudin* analysis textbook (does it cover that)?

Comment: NOOOO, you cannot.

Comment: I would suggest reading Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds* prior to opening Baby Rudin. Rudin is an unforgiving author in his expository texts by most accounts. (I think his more advanced books are actually quite readable though.)

Comment: If you're trying to learn multivariable calculus — with computations *and* rigor both — à la Spivak, I would recommend you look at Hubbard and Hubbard or my own text, Multivariable Mathematics. Both texts integrate linear algebra seriously into the multivariable calculus and prove everything.

Comment: @CameronWilliams *Calculus on Manifolds* is not exactly any more forgiving than Rudin.

Comment: Multivariable calculus is a subject that is easy to understand intuitively, but quite challenging to develop rigorousIy. And baby Rudin (and Calculus on Manifolds) does not bother to teach the simple intuition.  So I think there is a danger in learning multivariable calculus straight from Rudin -- one might not realize how easy multivariable calculus is.

Comment: Another 5 cent. Basically, I agree with @littleO. Personally, I've first learned the more rigorous $\mathbb{R}^n$ "approach" and only later encountered the $\mathbb{R}^3$ "approach". The transition although was pretty smooth as you view all the $n=3$ versions as a special cases of the "generalized" ones, but with the benefit of hindsight, I would do the opposite. Start with the intuitive approach and only then turning to the more rigorous.

Answer (score 1):

Having gone from Spivak's *Calculus* directly to Rudin's *Principles* myself, I would say the transition is fairly smooth. It would be ideal to have seen multivariable from somewhere by chapter 9, but up through chapter 8 there is no real need for that sort of material.

On another note, I recommend finding another reference for multivariable than Rudin; starting from chapter 9, my opinion is that his exposition gets considerably and irreversibly messier. Try to find something that has a lot of more computational exercises (the kind of book that a non-honors multivariable calculus course might use at your university, perhaps); multivariable calculus is valuable, and deserves a lot of practice.

Answer (score 0):

This is less of an answer, and more a recounting of my personal experience.

I went through baby Rudin without previously having taken Calc III, and the result is that for me, whenever I want to understand something in 3-d calculus, I think in terms of $n$ dimensions, and then specialize to $n = 3$. For instance, I couldn't tell you the low-dimensional Stokes's theorem or divergence theorem in the formulations involving normal vectors and such off the top of my head.

I don't know anyone else who has done this, but I suspect that anyone going through the multivariate part of Rudin without outside reading would develop similarly idiosyncratically.